# Tabbed App: TabLayout / ViewPager - Error caused by upgrading Gradle & Support library

Tags: java, android

My code was working pre-update, i updated my grandle & support libraries etc and it stopped working.
trying to fix it only caused a loop reaction.

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class DashboardLightActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPageAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboardlight);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentRed(), "Red");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentYellow(), "Yellow");
        adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentGreen(), "Green");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.settings_icon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.seatbelt_symbol);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.srs);
    }
}
```

```java
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my dependencies list. it might be wrong implementation but it should of worked

```java
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

grandle project: bugged version?

```java
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

The error i get while running the app:

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mac.ben.carlendar, PID: 7688
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mac.ben.carlendar/com.mac.ben.carlendar.DashboardLightActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mac.ben.carlendar:layout/activity_dashboardlight: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mac.ben.carlendar:layout/activity_dashboardlight: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.TabLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mac.ben.carlendar:layout/activity_dashboardlight: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mac.ben.carlendar:layout/activity_dashboardlight: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.TabLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.mac.ben.carlendar:layout/activity_dashboardlight: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.TabLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.TabLayout
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.mac.ben.carlendar.DashboardLightActivity.onCreate(DashboardLightActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.TabLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 28 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1852)
                ... 6 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.mac.ben.carlendar-PeGPUttOAmlYqdU8pGOO0Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1852)
                ... 6 more
```

how to make the same code work as before, or what changes necessary to make it work again. the code haven't been changed.

Comment: what are the errors? please share them as well

Comment: If you have set targetSdkVersion to 29 then you need to upgrade your all views using androidx. Also you will need to reimport your views in java and also need to change it in xml.

Comment: i changed the targetSdkVersion to 29 right now, did the changes in the xml:        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
AND IT WORKS. Thank you .

Comment: Great. You're welcome :-)